# Bugged nginx server

Tags: nginx

I currently have an nginx setup with the following config:

```
worker_processes  10;

error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  4000;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  30;
    keepalive_requests  100000;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH; 
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    # http server
server {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    listen 80; # IPv4
    server_name localhost;

    ## Parameterization using hostname of access and log filenames.
    access_log logs/localhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/localhost_error.log;

    ## Root and index files.
    root html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error).
    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Don't log robots.txt requests.
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP.
    location / {

        ## Regular PHP processing.
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        ## Static files
        location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay on;
            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
            open_file_cache_valid 30s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors on;
        }

        ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files.
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
            expires 30d;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
        }
        } # / location

} # end http server

# https server
server {
    listen 443 spdy ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate      my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  my.key;

    ## Parameterization using hostname of access and log filenames.
    access_log logs/localhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/localhost_error.log;

    ## Root and index files.
    root html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error).
    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Don't log robots.txt requests.
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP.
    location / {

        ## Regular PHP processing.
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        ## Static files are served directly.
        location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
        }

        ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files.
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
            expires 30d;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
        }
        } # / location
} # end https server
}
```

The web server seems to be lagging. Allowing .htaccess download periodically, sometimes an error will occur server side (or so I suspect) and the web server will begin serving pages that I did not request or that were previously requested (even if I explicitly demand index.php I will be served some other non-related page) overall it's a very worrisome behavior.

Can anyone give some clues?

Comment: "web server will begin serving pages that I did not request" - what do you mean by this? Also what version of nginx? Is your OS fully updated/patched?

Comment: I am running nginx 1.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 (I know).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent downloading of .ht* files (ex .htaccess/.htpasswd) you have to add this line to your config

```
location ~ /\.ht          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
```

Please define your occurrently error more accurate without defined error messages it's impossible to give you some advice.